# How can I force ticks/grid lines on a Highcharts datetime X axis to arbitrarily line up with data points?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, highcharts

I'm working on a highcharts chart using the lazy_high_charts ruby gem.  The x-axis represents consecutive date, with labels on every third one.  However, I seem to have no control over WHICH dates the labels appear under, and along with that, no control over where the grid lines appear.  Regardless of what date the chart begins or ends, it seems "locked" into assigning the ticks to certain dates and I can't figure out a way to change it.

This has another annoying side effect, since I am using startOnTick and endOnTick set to true: sometimes the data series lines appear flush with the left side of the chart (and in this case do line up with the gridlines/ticks/labels), and sometimes they begin to the right of the leftmost value.

I have tried all that I can think of and haven't found a solution that makes things look nice and consistent.  What I want is to have gridlines/ticks/labels on the left and right sides of the chart, with the first label lining up with the first data point, regardless of what day that happens to be on.

(EDIT: I can't post the below screenshots, unfortunately, because I'm a new user...if I manage to get 10 rep points I'll upload them)
Here are screenshots showing two dates ranges that illustrate both scenarios:

As you can see, in both cases the labels/ticks/gridlines fall on exactly the same dates, even though the time ranges are different.
(EDIT: see above)

Below are the chart options I am using.  Apologies that they are in ruby syntax, but they get translated straightforwardly into javascript.  Other than this issue, the chart is appearing exactly as I want it to, so I don't want to make any changes that will compromise any part of the appearance.  Thanks!

```
f.options[:title] = nil

  f.options[:legend] = { :enabled => false }

  f.options[:chart] = {
    :defaultSeriesType => "line",
    :height => 342,
    :width => 760,
    :opacity => 0.0,
    :style => "{ width: 760px; height: 342px; }",
    :borderColor => '#000000',
    :plotBorderColor => '#000000',
    :labels => "{ color: '#000000'; }",
    :spacingLeft => 25,
    :spacingRight => 25,
  }

  f.options[:xAxis] = {
    :type => 'linear',
    :gridLineWidth => 1,
    :gridLineDashStyle => 'ShortDash',
    :startOnTick => true,
    :endOnTick => true,
    :showLastLabel => true,
    :tickInterval => 3.days * 1000,
    :tickLength => 10,
    :tickWidth => 1,
    :tickPosition => 'inside',
    :tickmarkPlacement => 'on',
    :minorGridLineWidth => 0,
    :minorGridLineDashStyle => 'Dot',
    :minorTickInterval => 1.day * 1000,
    :minorTickLength => 5,
    :minorTickWidth => 1,
    :offset => 15,
    :minorTickPosition => 'inside',
    :lineWidth => 0,
    :labels => { :align => 'center', :step => 1 },
    :min => "2012-01-09".to_datetime.to_i * 1000,
    :max => "2012-01-09".to_datetime.to_i * 1000 + 29.days * 1000,
  }

  f.options[:yAxis] = {
    :title => { :text => nil },
    :type => 'linear',
    :gridLineWidth => 0,
    :min => 0,
    :max => 100,
    :labels => { :enabled => false }
  }
  f.series(:name=>'SeriesA', :data=>[29.9, 71.5, 54.4, 98, 2, 14.0, 23.6, 65.5, 34.4, 88.1], :color => "#D846AD", :pointStart => "2012-01-09".to_datetime.to_i * 1000, :pointInterval => 3.days * 1000)
  f.series(:name=>'SeriesB', :data=> [40.9, 71.5, 32.4, 12.2, 12.0, 32.0, 43.6, 34.5, 56.4, 87.1], :color => "#0A96C9", :pointStart => "2012-01-09".to_datetime.to_i * 1000, :pointInterval => 3.days * 1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell if this is the exact issue that you're having without seeing the screenshots, but if your problem is what I think it is, here is the solution:

Try setting `minPadding` and `maxPadding` to 0 for the relevant axis along with `startOnTick: true` and `endOnTick: true`.  Supposedly the behavior of `startOnTick` and `endOnTick` gets overridden if you don't also set the padding.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the automatic adjustment of the datetime labels.
Highcharts will take the date of a point and set the axis label according to its own logic.

For example if your axis spans several years it may display Aug 2012 or even just the year.
So what you see as assigning the date 01.Aug 2012 to the axis in reality Highcharts is displaying a date representation that it finds suitable for the axis scale.

You can control this behavior by setting the DateTimeLabelFormat for your xAxis:

> dateTimeLabelFormats : Object For a datetime axis, the scale will
>   automatically adjust to the appropriate unit. This member gives the
>   default string representations used for each unit. For an overview of
>   the replacement codes, see dateFormat. Defaults to:

see [HighCharts Reference](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/ref/#xAxis--dateTimeLabelFormats)

So all you have to do is change this:

```
{
    second: '%H:%M:%S',
    minute: '%H:%M',
    hour: '%H:%M',
    day: '%e. %b',
    week: '%e. %b',
    month: '%b \'%y',
    year: '%Y'
}
```

to something like

```
{
    second: '%H:%M:%S',
    minute: '%H:%M',
    hour: '%H:%M',
    day: '%e. %b',
    week: '%e. %b',
    month: '%e. %b',
    year: '%e. %b %Y'
}
```

to get it to display:

> %e: Day of the month, 1 through 31. 
>   and 
>   %b: Short month, like 'Jan'.

So for example it will display 23. Jan for your point for an axis scale of day or above and 23. Jan 2012 for a scale over a year.

Another Method would be to force the chart to display your values. I don't think that is advisable in a datetime line chart but here is an example:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CzHyC/22/)

And here the [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683695/yaxis-values-on-high-chart-customization/11741878#11741878) with a bit more detail