# Yaxis Values on High Chart Customization

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have been trying to populate yaxis values on my highchart as per defined by me and results should be shown accordingly but all my efforts are in vain i am not able to manually set `this.value` of yaxis of highchart . Following is a link to my Jsfiddle . Kindly help..

http://jsfiddle.net/CzHyC/12/

In the following JS COde I have been trying to set the `this.value` of yaxis to the arrayed values of yAxisLabels but values are not being labled and chart is not dislayed accordingly.

**JS CODE FOR YAXIS**

```
var yAxisLabels = ['5','10','20','30','40','50'];


yAxis: {
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            for (i=0; i<=5; i++) {
                this.value=yAxisLabels[i];
                return this.value;
            }
        }
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Total fruit consumption'
    },
    stackLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        style: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'blue'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Tick Positioner to define your axis tick values:

[See jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CzHyC/22/)

The important parts are:

```
var yAxisLabels = [0, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50];
```

your axis label array containing numbers and not strings

and

```
tickPositioner: function() {
                return yAxisLabels;
            },
```

the tickPositioner returning your array.

[TickPositioner Documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/ref/#yAxis--tickPositioner)

Comment: Correct but chart is not representing values as per Yaxis label i want chart should be populated as per yaxis labels.

Comment: Sorry i don't really get what you want to do. Do you want to set the datalabel (the blue bold value above the bars)?

Answer (score 0):

you can also set like this

```
tickPositions: [0, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
```